# Elastic Search - How to import data?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, rake, tire

When I run

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Article.all' INDEX='mongo-articles' FORCE=true
```

To import data in Elastic Search

```
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tire:import (first_time)
** Execute tire:import
[IMPORT] Deleting index 'mongo-articles'
rake aborted!
undefined method `tire' for #<Tire::Results::Collection:0xabec954>
/home/helios/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@munksearch/gems/tire-0.5.1/lib /tire/tasks.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => tire:import
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: not sure what trouble you're running into here (seems like an issue with Tire). However, there is a new gem being written for the new v1.0 version of elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails. The author is the same as for Tire, and the gem is already quite stable.

Comment: @jay btw I have already update the tire gem though same error ..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.all` from `Article.all`.

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Article' INDEX='mongo-articles' FORCE=true
```

Also I'd suggest removing the INDEX argument and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Can you show the full error response for `rake environment tire:import CLASS='Article'`

Comment: Note the README uses 'Article' and not 'Article.all' https://github.com/karmi/retire (which makes sense as Article is the class name, Article.all is just a Ruby expression which won't be evaluated as you may be expecting).